# Обратиться к DataTable через SQL запрос

Tags: c#, база-данных, wpf

Приветствую. Есть dataset с несколькими таблицами. Как организовать запрос к таблицам dataset'a что бы выбрать определенные строки. Если бы я обращался к базе то написал бы обычный запрос в SQLCommand а как поступить если нужно выбрать строку из таблицы в DataSet ?

Comment: Можно `dataTable.AsEnumerable()` и далее linq-запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение для выборки строк из DataTable

```
        string i = cmb_NumbersOrders.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DataTable tableS = DAL.ShowAllClient();  //возвращает DataTable
        DataRow[] findRow;
        string expression = $"`Order` LIKE '{i}'"; // sql подобный запрос
        findRow = tableS.Select(expression);

        lbl_Info.Content = findRow[0][4].ToString() + " ";  //отобразить значение из 4го столбца
```